# Running a gradle project from eclipse does nothing

Tags: gradle

I was wondering why if I hit run in my gradle project, It does nothing really. 
It asks me "Select a way to run Game.java" and it does nothing, No opening, nothing,.
If you have a solution, Please tell me :)!
(Or this may just be a stupid question/me)

Answer (score 0):

If you're on the context menu for a source file and tried to select "Run As ...", then this is an appropriate response.  You just said "I hit run in my gradle project", which doesn't tell us much.

You might try right-clicking on the project or the "build.gradle" file and selecting an appropriate menu item.